# Discord.js - Why __.cache.get() codes didn't work and an error alert "fn is not a function" appeared in the Command Prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fn

Hello there and thank you so much for your visit to the question :D.
Here is a piece of code I've written:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < game.channels.length; i++) {
  let channel = msg.guild.channels.cache.find(game.channels[i]); //Line number 249
  msg.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.id).delete();
}
for (let i = 0; i < game.players.length; i++) {
  let member = msg.guild.members.cache.find(game.players[i]);
  console.log(member); //I used this line to see what "member" stored
  msg.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.remove(alive);
}
for (let i = 0; i < game.watchers.length; i++) {
  let member = msg.guild.members.cache.find(game.watchers[i]);
  console.log(member); //I used this line to see what "member" stored
  msg.guild.members.cache.get(member.id).roles.remove(dead);
}
for (let i = 0; i < game.werewolf.length; i++) {
  msg.guild.channels.cache
    .find((c) => c.name == "werewolf-chat" && c.type == "text")
    .permissionOverwrites.get(game.werewolf[i])
    .delete();
}
```

My *goals* are to:

- **[In the 1st loop]** Delete channels with their IDs defined in `game.channels`.
- **[In the 2nd loop]** Remove a role named "Alive" (which has its ID store as `alive`) from users with their IDs defined in `game.players`.
- **[In the 3rd loop]** Remove a role named "Dead" (which has its ID store as `alive`) from users with their IDs defined in `game.watchers`.
- **[In the 4th loop]** Delete a channel's permissions for users with their IDs defined in `game.werewolf`.

*However*, none of the goals above is achieved; instead, in the Command Prompt, this appeared:

```
C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:160
            if (fn(val, key, this))
                ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
    at Map.find (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:160:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\bot.js:249:56)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
```

Looking forward to your help to fix this problem. Once again, thank you for your caring.
***P/s:*** I'm very new to Javascript and Discord bot developing, so I'm highly grateful if you can answer this question in the clearest and most detailed as you possibly can.

Comment: get function uses a callback which looks something like `x => condition`

Comment: @DenverCoder9 You mean `find` ? The problem here code is that @Ahn Duy Bùi used  `find` instead of `get` on the first three loops.

Comment: @Tenclea yeah, I meant `find`

Comment: @DenverCoder9 Thanks for reminding me with that!  A bit further question, is it possible for using member’s ID for the condition in that callback?

Comment: @AnhDuyBùi You'd need to replace the first `.find` in each loop (not the last one) with `.get`